# How to edit a View in DB2 IBM iseries instead of deleting and then create it again?

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange

How can I alter or edit a view in DB2 through System i Navigator?  I don't know how, as it deletes other views built on it.

Comment: Alter / edit what?  Table contents?  Schema?

Comment: a "view". This is how they are named in DB2. They are queries saved as tables but their name is "view".

Comment: Sorry, missed the 'view' part.

I took a look at my copy of iNav and can't see a way to edit views.

You might want to check out today's webcast that COMMON Is presenting on using System i Navigator ... http://common.org/index.php/webcasts/upcoming-webcasts.html#jan

Comment: you know: in a DB you can have views, tables, functions and other stuff..

Comment: Why not just delete and rebuild it?  Your question refers to "other views built on it", but you can't base a view on a view (and if you could the iSeries wouldn't let you delete the based-on one).

Comment: well but it allows. I have a view that has a lot of other views based on it, so in order to make a change to this "root" view I must drop it and then change it. When I drop it, every view is deleted too...

Comment: I would create a new view and not touch the original.  There is no chance of failure with a new view.

Comment: Imagine I have the following dependency: A needs B and B need C. Now I want to change C, then I create C1 and I have to write the A1 and B1 views again. Then everything that depended on view A must be updated to A1, just for a little where select change.

Answer (score 5):

There's no way to alter a view using iSeries Navigator. However, if you are open to using a SQL statement AND you are on v7.1 or greater, you can use the new "CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW" command: [SQL CREATE OR REPLACE syntax](http://iprodeveloper.com/database/use-sql-create-or-replace-improve-db2-i-object-management).

This will allow you to alter existing views without first needing to drop dependent objects. For example consider a view named "VIEW2" that consumes a column named "DESC" from "VIEW1". You could add a column to "VIEW1" without affecting "VIEW2" using the following command:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW MYSCHEMA.VIEW1 AS
    SELECT DESC, NEWCOL FROM MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE;
```

Similarly, you can drop a column from "VIEW1" without affecting other views. The only restriction is that you cannot drop a column that is used by another view (or function, alias, etc.) If you try to drop a column that another view is dependent upon, you will receive an error message.

Using the "REPLACE" method will also preserve any permissions/security constraints.

It should be noted that a more ideal method would be to automate the creation of views/functions/procs/aliases/etc via scripts. This would allow you to drop and recreate dependent objects in a consistent manner. This presumes some manner of automation around your database management, and may present issues if you have a very large number of dependent objects (of if you have a large number of indexed views.) The biggest risk with having a large number of "REPLACE" scripts is that they will be applied incorrectly, either by not applying one of the scripts or by applying them in the wrong order.

Comment: But will drop views based on that view?

Comment: I've added some additional information to clarify how the "REPLACE" command affects other views.

Comment: the problem of dropping and creating again is that we have to set the permissions again and the internal name changes. One view named bla_bla_bla is truncated to bla_0001 for example. Next time you drop and create will be bla_0002 and other stuff will not work anymore

Comment: @Totty.js Add the FOR SYSTEM NAME clause on the CREATE statement [if available on the release of DB2 for IBM i being used; seems left unstated in the OP], to explicitly assign the desired *system* aka *short* name.